# Get variable memory usage in Go 1.3.1

Tags: go

1. Why this code can not found the memory usage (m2-m1) and (m4-m3)?
2. Why (m3-m2) and (m5-m4) require to allocate extra memory?

[Full code here](http://play.golang.org/p/5TorN6aD0_)

```
type T struct {
    B uint8
    S string
    I int
}

func memUsage(mOld, mNew *runtime.MemStats) {
    fmt.Println("Alloc:", mNew.Alloc-mOld.Alloc,
        "HeapAlloc:", mNew.HeapAlloc-mOld.HeapAlloc,
        "TotalAlloc:", mNew.TotalAlloc-mOld.TotalAlloc)
}
func main() {
    var m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6 runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m1)
    t := T{}
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m2)
    fmt.Println(t)
    memUsage(&m1, &m2)

    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m3)
    t2 := "abc"
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m4)
    fmt.Println(t2)
    memUsage(&m3, &m4)

    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m5)
    t3 := map[int]string{1: "x"}
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m6)
    fmt.Println(t3)
    memUsage(&m5, &m6)

    memUsage(&m2, &m3)
    memUsage(&m4, &m5)
}
```

Output

```
{0  0}
Alloc: 0 HeapAlloc: 0 TotalAlloc: 0
abc
Alloc: 0 HeapAlloc: 0 TotalAlloc: 0
map[1:x]
Alloc: 256 HeapAlloc: 256 TotalAlloc: 256
Alloc: 432 HeapAlloc: 432 TotalAlloc: 432
Alloc: 64 HeapAlloc: 64 TotalAlloc: 64
```

Comment: Don't use invalid [`fmt`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) printing verbs; `%u` is invalid. I fixed it for you.

Comment: Use `unsafe.Sizeof(t)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `t` is allocated on the stack.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type T struct {
    B uint8
    S string
    I int
}

func main() {
    t := T{}
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Pseudo-assembler:

```
0x0021 00033 (t.go:14)  LEAQ    "".statictmp_0002+0(SB),BX
0x0028 00040 (t.go:14)  LEAQ    "".t+88(SP),BP
0x002d 00045 (t.go:14)  MOVQ    BP,DI
0x0030 00048 (t.go:14)  MOVQ    BX,SI
0x0033 00051 (t.go:14)  DUFFCOPY    ,$
```

References:

[A Manual for the Plan 9 assembler](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/asm.html)

---

You have revised your question substantially. Next time, ask a new question.

You muddy the waters by your calls to the `fmt` package. All we can see is that the `fmt` package does some heap allocations. We would have to trace through hundreds of lines of code in the `fmt` package to see what is happening. Also, the results are not reproducible.

I removed all the clutter:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

type T struct {
    B uint8
    S string
    I int
}

func memUsage(mOld, mNew *runtime.MemStats) {
    fmt.Println("Alloc:", mNew.Alloc-mOld.Alloc,
        "HeapAlloc:", mNew.HeapAlloc-mOld.HeapAlloc,
        "TotalAlloc:", mNew.TotalAlloc-mOld.TotalAlloc)
}
func main() {
    var m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7 runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m1)
    t := T{}
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m2)
    _ = t
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m3)
    t2 := "abc"
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m4)
    _ = t2
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m5)
    t3 := map[int]string{1: "x"}
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m6)
    _ = t3
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m7)

    memUsage(&m1, &m2)
    memUsage(&m2, &m3)
    memUsage(&m3, &m4)
    memUsage(&m4, &m5)
    memUsage(&m5, &m6)
    memUsage(&m6, &m7)
}
```

Output:

```
Alloc: 0 HeapAlloc: 0 TotalAlloc: 0
Alloc: 0 HeapAlloc: 0 TotalAlloc: 0
Alloc: 0 HeapAlloc: 0 TotalAlloc: 0
Alloc: 0 HeapAlloc: 0 TotalAlloc: 0
Alloc: 256 HeapAlloc: 256 TotalAlloc: 256
Alloc: 0 HeapAlloc: 0 TotalAlloc: 0
```

It's easy to see that the stack is used except for creating the map which uses the stack and the heap.

Note: Go memory management is implementation dependent. It's frequently improved and it's about to be completely rewritten.

Comment: @DanielYCLin: For example, on amd64, `go tool 6g -S source.go`. [Run specified go tool](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Run_specified_go_tool) and [Commands](http://golang.org/cmd/).